# “I wish we don't do that again in the future” or “I wish we would not do that in the future"

Tags: tense

This evening, I was out with my friend, and during our conversation he said, “It's very long time since we last came this far” and to which I replied, “I wish we don't do that again in the future”.

Following this we had a debate. He said, my comment, “I wish we don't do that again in the future” was wrong, and it should have been, "I wish we would not do that in the future".

Could you please tell me which sentence is correct in this context?

“I wish we don't do that again in the future” or “I wish we would not do that in the future".

Comment: /I hope we don't do that again in the future/. Wish is not right here. That's the issue. Also, I wish + would expresses a PRESENT idea that is unreal: I wish he would shut up [now, but he won't, he's still talking!]. Get it? :) I wish  you were rich [now]; I wish they would leave [now]. All those are ideas in the present that are not  happening. :)

Comment: @Lambie "Wish" does no really work with a negative. I think that's the problem. As you say, "hope" is the better word.

Answer (score 1):

- I hope we can find time for each other more often.
- I hope we do not (have to) wait this long to see each other next
  time.
- In the future, let's not wait so long between visits.

I think it is simply awkward use of language and the only thing that matters is that you ended up understanding what was meant. The first time I read it, I thought you did not want to see your friend, not because it is what you said but because it was awkward.

Answer (score -1):

Your friend is correct.  When talking about wishes or hopes in the future, [it's appropriate to use "would".](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/wishes-and-hypotheses)

> I wish it would rain tomorrow
>
> I wish we would go to Europe next summer.

As in your example, this can also be negative:

> I wish he would not cough so much.
>
> I wish it wouldn't rain this week.

In your example, though, it's not necessary to use "wish".  Other ways to say the same thing:

> This was a bad idea.  Let's not do this ever again.
>
> I think it's best we never do this again.

Comment: Andrew:  I wish she would shut up (present). It is not a future./ I wish it would rain [now ]because the other one is  /I hope it rains tomorrow/.